# linking to a part of bytes object in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I need to have an original object (bytes) and this object minus last 20 bytes in python 3. I can do like this:

```
b = a[0:-20]
```

but it makes a copy of my object. Can I save memory linking to a part of an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, use a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview):

```
b = memoryview(a)[:-20]
```

As the documentation notes:

> `memoryview` objects allow Python code to access the internal data of an object that supports the buffer protocol without copying.